# How to list all wallet UTxOs with cardano-cli?

Tags: cardano-cli, transaction, utxo

How to list all wallet's UTxOs with `cardano-cli` utility? Not only address UTxOs via:

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address <ADDRESS> --mainnet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wallet does not contain UTxOs, only addresses do. Therefore, you first need to derive all your addresses for your wallet and then check it one by one using the command in question.